# Curl "Connection Refused" when connecting to server with external IP address

Tags: python, curl, networking, portforwarding

I've created a RESTful server and I can successfully make requests and get responses when I use my local IP address.  I would like it to be exposed externally to the internet.  I set up a port forwarding rule but I cannot seem to get things working.  From what I'm reading the "Connection Refused" with (7) means something is blocking it whether it's a firewall or ISP issue.  Any ideas on what to do?

Here's my curl command that works with my local IP:

```
Pako-2:Pokebot pako$ curl -X GET http://192.168.1.8:30000/api/v1/getrecord/test
{"data": [{"id": 1, "title": "learn python"}, {"id": 2, "title": "get paid"}]}
```

This is what I see when I try using my external IP address given to me by [What's my ip](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)

```
Pako-2:Pokebot pako$ curl -X GET http://MyIpHere:30000/api/v1/getrecord/test
curl: (7) Failed to connect to myIPAddress port 30000: Connection refused
```

Here's the port forwarding rule I made in my router/modem
[image]

Here are my router/modem advanced settings options.  I tried tweaking my firewall settings, but no luck.  I tried with NAT only and also with Low Security Level with all ports checked.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

-----------------Edit-----------------

Here is the port forwarding screen, should I just set 30000 as the begin and end? 
[image]

Here is some python code for my server:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading
import argparse
import re
import cgi
import json


TODOS = [
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'learn python'},
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'get paid'},
]

class LocalData(object):
    records = {}


class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    print "HTTPRequestHandler BaseHTTPRequestHandler = ", BaseHTTPRequestHandler
    def do_POST(self):
        print "do_POST"
        if None != re.search('/api/v1/addrecord/*', self.path):
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'application/json':
                length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
                data = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length), keep_blank_values=1)
                recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]
                LocalData.records[recordID] = data
                print "record %s is added successfully" % recordID
            else:
                data = {}
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
        else:
            self.send_response(403)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()
        return

    def do_GET(self):
        print "do_GET"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'data': TODOS}))
        return


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def shutdown(self):
        self.socket.close()
        HTTPServer.shutdown(self)


class SimpleHttpServer():
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.server = ThreadedHTTPServer((ip, port), HTTPRequestHandler)

    def start(self):
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        self.server_thread.daemon = True
        self.server_thread.start()

    def waitForThread(self):
        self.server_thread.join()

    def addRecord(self, recordID, jsonEncodedRecord):
        LocalData.records[recordID] = jsonEncodedRecord

    def stop(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.waitForThread()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SimpleHttpServer("0.0.0.0", 30000)


    print 'HTTP Server Running...........'
    server.start()
    server.waitForThread()
```

------------------- Edit 2--------------------

Tried only having 1 port, not a begin/end range and it's expecting a range...
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to not put a Remote IP address

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm not a networking guru.

Comment: Don't enter in `0.0.0.0` in the interface. Also, why did you add a range of ports when you only need to open `30000`?

Comment: You may also want to set DHCP reservation for your server. In other words, set a static IP address

Comment: Yes, I'll add some more details about my python server code,  server = SimpleHttpServer("0.0.0.0", 30000)

I did try to set a static IP but ran into some issues, i'll try again.  The port forwarding screen asked for a begin range and end range.  It didn't ask for just one port.  I added some code

Comment: Look at the 4567 port forwarding line. That's exactly what you should try to copy, but you just need to set a local IP for the server

Comment: And two things - How are you testing this? If you are within your local network, then the router is going to ignore your usage of the external IP. Also, I'm sure your server is fine, but this looks quite involved compared to Flask (or any other Python web server library)

Comment: Trying to copy the 4567 rule... It seems to expect a range (I added more pictures showing the error messages) I'll keep trying things.

Comment: The second popup seems reasonable if you didn't delete the existing rule

Comment: I'm testing using my curl command at the top which is doing a GET.  If I use my local IP address 192.168.1.8 it works, but using my external IP it does not work.  I am using a home network.  The router/modem was given to me by my Verizon DSL ISP.  My laptop is the server and it's connected to the router/modem wirelessly.

Comment: So I've deleted the old range.  The web page won't just let me input one single port.  Same error message.  I can enter the following range though
30000/30000 TCP 192.168.1.8 30000/30000 0.0.0.0

Comment: It may depend on the router, but, for example, if I use my external IP, the router knows that it is using that interface, so no "outside" connection from the internet is going to be made. At least, that's been my limited networking experience. If you want to test the external firewall, you need a device not on the same network as the router

Comment: That's exactly what was happening.  I connected my other laptop to my phones wifi hot spot so it wasn't on this home network.  It worked!  Thanks for your help.  Feel free to answer the question so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it strange that you'd be getting connection refused from within the local network because the router should be able to detect that the external IP is a reference to itself.

That ability may depend on the router, but that's been my experience with networking.

That being said, if you'd like to test the external firewall after playing with the port forwarding rules, then you need a device not on the local network.

If another device like a smart phone with a cell plan isn't available to you, then you could try to use [CanYouSeeMe](http://www.canyouseeme.org) to test if the port is being opened.

You may also want to set DHCP reservation for your server. In other words, set a static IP address.

Comment: http://www.canyouseeme.org/ is a great tool, thanks again!  Yep, static IP is next on the todo list for this project.

Comment: hello @cricket_007. i am also getting below error when i try to pull yarn data using curl from local host. Error messae => Connection refused * Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.101:6188; Connection refused. do i need to fix anything on the settings of VM

Comment: @akash I don't recognize that port. I suggest you create a new post rather than ask questions in the comments, but port access is checked with netcat, not curl